# Lock screen weather not working

Tags: lock-screen

I have a Nokia Lumia 635 with Windows Phone 8.1, and I use the default MSN Weather app, which has a feature that allows me to set the lock screen to show the weather. However, while the app and its live tile both update as they should, the weather lock screen does not -- in fact, it stays blank with a blue background.

I know that I could use another app to do this for me, such as AccuWeather but I'm just curious as to why Microsoft's own app fails to work properly in that regard. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: That very app works for me. Have you disallowed Weather to run in the background (via the Battery app)?

Comment: No. In fact, I checked the status of it in the Battery Saver app, and it was allowed to run in the background. I seem to have the same problem with other pre-installed apps as well, such as the Facebook app.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured out the problem. The app needs to be installed on the phone itself, not the SD card. So I uninstalled it and reinstalled it accordingly.

I found that out [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/newmsn/forum/newmsn_set-newmsn_locset/msn-weather-help-hub/6f5a55af-5ef6-479b-82c9-b11ca0c748b8), under *Known Live tile / Lock screen issues*.

Comment: I don't think you need to reinstall it, just move. I think it was what I did when i happened.

Comment: Great answer! A side note: Microsoft (and other publishers) already marks some of apps (like OneDrive) as not allowed to be moved to SD Card. Why it simply can't mark MSN Weather the same way, if it is known to cause troubles, when moved to SD Card? Logic in Microsoft often thrills me!

Comment: Just a note here that I have this installed on my phone and it does not automatically update on the lock screen or live tile for that matter. Lumia 735
8.1 update 2

Comment: Allow Weather app to run in background & allow it to show weather on lock screen by going in to setting then lock screen. There select an app to show detailed status, select weather app. This worked for me on Lumia 730 on Windows 10 Mobile. Try it.